Why did Jewish leaders change their mind on the arrest and execution of Jesus?
We read in Mtt 26:3-5(NIV);

Then the chief priests and the elders of the people assembles in the palace of the high priest, whose name was Caiaphas,  and they schemed to arrest Jesus secretly and kill him.  “But not during the festival,” they said, “or there may be a riot among the people.”

<  But we see Jesus getting arrested on a day of Passover and getting crucified on the Day of Preparation ( Jn 19:14)  Apparently, the Jewish leaders had a change of mind vis- a- vis their original apprehension in Mtt 26: 5. The Gospels do not record the reason for the shift. Are there any apocryphal writings on the subject ?

I think it was the last day of the feast, so they did avoid killing him during the week long festival, but waited until the end to avoid uproar.

Thanks, Michael16. But, what does Preparation in Jn 19:14 mean ?

That is, Friday of passover week, the preparation day before the Sabbath of passover week (or feast). See also verses John 19:31; John 19:42; Mark 15:42; Matt 27:62; Luke 23:54 . Friday literally means day of preparation (for Shabbath).

Then the Jewish leaders took Jesus from Caiaphas to the palace of the Roman governor. By now it was early morning, and to avoid ceremonial uncleanness they did not enter the palace, because they wanted to be able to eat the Passover ( Jn 18:28). Does it not mean that Passover meal was eaten on Friday also ? Was Passover determined by days of the week say, Sunday to Friday and not by dates of the calendar say , from 10 th the 14 th ? Could Sabbath fall in between Passover celebration ?

It happened to fall on Friday that year.

19 Now Pilate wrote a title and put it on the cross. And the writing was:
JESUS OF NAZARETH, THE KING OF THE JEWS.
20 Then many of the Jews read this title, for the place where Jesus was crucified was near the city ( Jn 19:20) . Since it was most important feast, thousands would have assembled in Jerusalem .  They would have stayed put   . An uproar over Jesus' crucifixion could never be overruled. I have the feeling that Judas Iscariot had turned a rebel and suo moto promised to betray his Master, and that led the leaders into believing that Jesus' disciples would not lead  an uproar .
